# piplinedRDD can't convert to dataframe using toDF

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, rdd

I have a pyspark dataframe contains rows of data seperated by comma. I want to split each row and apply LabeledPoints method to it. Then covnert it to dataframe.

Here is my code

```
import os.path
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
import numpy as np
file_name = os.path.join('databricks-datasets', 'cs190', 'data-001',    'millionsong.txt')

raw_data_df = sqlContext.read.load(file_name, 'text')
rdd = raw_data_df.rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda seq:LabeledPoints(seq[0],seq[1:])).toDF()
```

It gives the following error message after apply .DF().

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 38.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 44, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-dc4d86a8ee45> in <module>()
----> 1 rdd = raw_data_df.rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda     seq:LabeledPoints(seq[0],seq[1:])).toDF()
  2 print(type(rdd))
  3 #print(rdd.take(5))

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in toDF(self, schema,     sampleRatio)
 62         [Row(name=u'Alice', age=1)]
 63         """
 ---> 64         return sqlContext.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
 65 
 66     RDD.toDF = toDF

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio)
421 
422         if isinstance(data, RDD):
```

--> 423             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data, schema, samplingRatio)
    424         else:
    425             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(data, schema)

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in _createFromRDD(self, rdd, schema, samplingRatio)
```

Comment: Typo: `LabeledPoint` != `LabeledPoints`

Comment: The problem still exist if I correct the typo. Even after removing the second map, it still cause error when using take() to show the lines after split.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found:
rdd = raw_data_df.map(lambda row: row['value'].split(',')).map(lambda seq:LabeledPoint(float(seq[0]),seq[1:])).toDF()

Here, I need to specifically reference each line of text using row['value'], even though there is only one feature in the row.